# View helper plugin extending in ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, view-helpers

I want to extend, for example, `Zend\View\Helper\HeadMeta` with my own class and I create a factory for it and call it by

```
public function getViewHelperConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'MyHeadMeta' => __NAMESPACE__ . '\View\Helper\Service\MyHeadMetaService',
        ),
    );
}
```

from `Module.php`, but I have

```
$this->view
```

is `null` in `MyHeadMeta` class if I call it by

```
$this->MyHeadMeta()->setCharset('utf-8');
```

in my view file.

How do I instantiate my view helper properly?

### UPDATE

My class looks something like this:

MyHeadMeta.php

```
use Zend\View\Helper\HeadMeta;

class MyHeadMeta extends HeadMeta
{
    //
}
```

### UPDATE 2

MyHeadMetaService.php

```
class MyHeadMetaService implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $viewHelper = new MyHeadMeta();
        // some settings to set...
        return $viewHelper;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your `MyHeadMetaService` look like?

Comment: Hi! I edited my question, in general it's just extend native `HeadMeta`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only extend the existing `HeadMeta` class then you should register it as an invokable [as is done with the original `HeadMeta` view helper](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-view/blob/master/src/HelperPluginManager.php#L57) in the `HelperPluginManager`.

So change your config like this:

```
return array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'MyHeadMeta' => 'View\Helper\Service\MyHeadMetaService'
    )
);
```

By the way I don't think it is necessary to use the full path with `__NAMESPACE__`. Just make sure the name points to the correct file and folder path of your class in the current module and declare the `namespace` constant in the class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I guess I need to do this with a factory 'cause I have a settings to set to global object. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @Dima Okay but I asked you to show `MyHeadMetaService` and what you are showing is an `invokable` and not a factory...

Comment: Hi! I edited my question again to show you the factory. It's pretty simple and common, nothing special. My factory doesn't work, but in HelperPluginManager.php factories are present.

Comment: @dima What exactly doesn't work now? Is the factory never called?